# JQuery - Underscore in match()

Tags: jquery, regex

I have an input to match only letters, but for some reason underscores also counts as ok symbol.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#first_name').bind('input', function() {
            if (!$(this).val().match("^[A-zА-я^_]{3,}$")) {
                $('#first_name').css('background-color', 'rgb(250,171,192)');
                $('#first_name').css('border-color', 'rgb(180,86,109)');
            }
            else {
                $('#first_name').css('background-color', 'rgb(193,256,159)');
                $('#first_name').css('border-color', 'rgb(31,122,23)');
            }
        });
    });

<input type="text" id="first_name" />
```

I added "^_" condition later but it works the same with and without it.

Comment: I just realised that backslash does the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A-z` includes ASCII 65 through 122 which includes the underscore (ASCII 95) :)

Use `A-Za-z`

`А-я` does the same thing again (for a larger range). So you need to be more specific about the subsets of characters to include.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `А-я` part. That says that you'll take any character anywhere from `A` to `я`. `_` and many, many other characters appear in that range. `A` is [code point U+0041](http://farsightsoftware.com/utils/unicode-show-me.html?A); `я` is [code point U+044F](http://farsightsoftware.com/utils/unicode-show-me.html?%D1%8F). So `A-я` means "anything from U+0041 through U+044F." `_` is [code point U+005F](http://farsightsoftware.com/utils/unicode-show-me.html?_), so it's in that range. So is `\` ([U+005C](http://farsightsoftware.com/utils/unicode-show-me.html?%5C)) and several hundred others.

To fix it, you'll need to list the ranges for valid characters separately in that character class, since `А-я` is far too broad. I don't know the alphabet you're using well enough to know what ranges are valid, but for instance you might start with `A-Za-z` (if all English characters are valid) and then add other ranges for the other valid characters.

---

> I added "^_" condition later but it works the same with and without it.

If you mean you added `^_` to that in an attempt to say "but not `_`", that's now how character classes work. They are either positive or negative. To be negative, the `^` must appear in the *first* position inside the `[]`. Adding `^_` to the end of the class just adds those two characters to the list of characters that you are happy to accept.